# how to convert an object into an array in a specific format in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an JSON object like

```
[{"schedule_time_id":1},{"schedule_time_id":2}]
```

I want to convert this JSON object into the following format

```
[1,2]
```

I have used already `(array) $object` to convert it but doesn't get the targeted format.

Comment: I assume that is a JSON String that you are starting with right?

Comment: Programming languages are generic tools that aim to help you in achieving specific tasks. They don't read your mind, they don't convert between every possible data structure. For solving this problem, there's `json_decode` and `foreach`/`array_map`. Try these, then come back if you need more help.

Comment: convert JSON into an array and then use [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly...right...I have edited already

Comment: @JigarShah The result of using your solution would be exactly the same as decoding the json string..

Comment: @Bartosz Zasada....`Programming languages are generic tools that aim to help you in achieving specific tasks. They don't read your mind, they don't convert between every possible data structure`
I know that my friend. I can't make the data structure for this...That's why I am asking here....

Comment: @MateiMihai, yeah, realized that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a json string. You can use `json_decode` to convert it an associative array

Like:

```
$str = '[{"schedule_time_id":1},{"schedule_time_id":2}]';
$arr = json_decode( $str, true );

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $arr );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will look like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [schedule_time_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [schedule_time_id] => 2
        )

)
```

If you want to convert it to simple array(Not associative array), you can use `array_column`

```
$newArr = array_column( $arr, 'schedule_time_id' );

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $newArr );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
```

---

**To make it shorter, you can:**

```
$str = '[{"schedule_time_id":1},{"schedule_time_id":2}]';
$newArr = array_column( json_decode( $str, true ) , 'schedule_time_id' );
```

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty possibilites to achieve that. One of them would be to use array map over the decoded json.

```
$result = array_map(function ($item) {
    return $item->schedule_time_id;
}, json_decode($json));
```

Comment: I was just about to post this solution; albeit I used the second parameter of `json_decode` to set it to true;)

Comment: not using the second parameter is a micro optimization.. but using it would give the same result

Comment: @Matei Mihai...your's one is also correct. But Eddie's one is more elaborate and understandable... So I accept his answer. Thanks my friend... :)